# how to distribute list items to class instance python

Tags: python, list, class

I am Trying to turn a list elements to a class instance. I have a list like the one below

```
new_value = ('TafaTIC', 'normal_user', '1', '19', False)
```

and a class just like this example

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name: str, level: str, ID: str, age: str, student: bool):
        self._name = name
        self._level = level
        self._id = ID
        self._age = age
        self._student = student
```

basically what I want is to distribute these element to this class in order to be like this in the end

```
Student = student('TafaTIC','normal_user','1','19',False)
```

Thank you in advance <3

Comment: Terminology note: *everything* is a "class object" in Python, in the sense you are using it. The term you are looking for is *instance of a class*. A "class object" is the *class itself*.

Comment: Maybe [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) are what are you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
Student = student(*new_value)
```

It should give the following:

```
print(Student._name)  # prints 'TafaTIC'
print(Student._level)  # prints 'normal_user'
print(Student._id)  # prints '1'
print(Student._age)  # prints '19'
print(Student._student)  # prints False
```

Comment: For completeness, the term for this syntactic form is [*argument unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments).

Comment: Alright Thanks for explaining <3